# Dispalys garbadge value for long int b

Tags: c++

Displays unexpected Output for `long int b`

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
using namespace std ;
int a;
long int b;
char c;
float d;
double e;
int main(){
    scanf("%d %ld %c %f %lf", &a , &b , &c , &d , &e);
    printf(" %d \n %ld \n %c \n %0.3f \n %0.9lf" , a , b , c , d , e);
   return 0;
}
```

Input:-

```
3 12345678912345 a 334.23 14049.30493
```

Output:-

```
 3
 1942903641
 a
 334.230
 14049.304930000
```

Comment: ¿Are you sure that 12345678912345 is within long int range?

Comment: [Your code works](https://wandbox.org/permlink/T7EI5q6kN0Z40NzV). What is your compiler? Use a compiler whose `long int` is 64-bit long.

Comment: `12345678912345`, if stored in a 32-bit twos complement `long int` will give the result of `1942903641`  (the lower 32 bits).      In practice, most modern compilers support a 32-bit `long int` - although larger representations are permitted.   Before C++20, a twos-complement representation for signed integral types is not required, and (assuming a 32-bit `long int`) your input gives undefined behaviour.  C++20 requires a twos-complement representation for signed integral types  (but the range of values that can be stored in a `long int` is still implementation-defined).